# PyQt Delegate with user defined widget

Tags: qt, delegates, pyqt, treeview

I'm trying to implement a Delegate in a TreeView. The Delegate shall consist of a LineEdit and a Button:

```
class Ui_Data_Delegate(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Ui_Data_Delegate, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 271, 61))
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.ToolButton = QToolButton(self)
        self.ToolButton.setObjectName("ToolButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.ToolButton)
```

In the createEditor function I call the Ui_Data_Delegate class:

```
def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):

    if type == UDF.DT_ResultsSelector:

        editor = Ui_Data_Delegate(parent)
        editor.ToolButton.released.connect(self.make_selection)
        return editor
    else:
        return QStyledItemDelegate.createEditor(self, parent, option, index)
```

But then I don't see any editor in the treeView:
[image]

If I miss the parent parameter:

```
def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):

    if type == UDF.DT_ResultsSelector:

        editor = Ui_Data_Delegate()
        editor.ToolButton.released.connect(self.make_selection)
        return editor
    else:
        return QStyledItemDelegate.createEditor(self, parent, option, index)
```

I get:

[image]

This is nearly correct but the widget should appear in the Treeview Cell!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. The Content Margins were not set.
So with this Code it works:

```
class Ui_Data_Delegate(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Ui_Data_Delegate, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)        
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.ToolButton = QToolButton(self)
        self.ToolButton.setObjectName("ToolButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.ToolButton)
```